# Integrating a list from a private api to a ListView

Tags: flutter, api, listview

I'm having issues with it for some reason, while running the app none of the cands (the list of objects) listed in the apis response gets displayed in the ListView.
This is the response im getting from the api:

```
{
"currentPage": 1,
"totalPages": 1,
"totalResults": 4, // that's the amount of events in the list
"candList": [
{
"fname": "string", 
"lname": "string"
}
]
}
```

I guess the issue starts somewhere in that part of code:

```
final num = getJsonField(listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody, r'''$.candList''',).toList();
if (num.isEmpty) {
return Center(
child: SworkerContainerWidget(
fname: GetCandListByManagerCall.workerfname(listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody,).toString(),
lname: GetCandListByManagerCall.workerlname(listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody,).toString(),),);
}
return ListView.builder(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: num.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, numIndex) {
                                final numItem = num[numIndex];
                                return InkWell(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    await Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            HistoryPageWidget(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: SworkerContainerWidget(
                                    desc: GetCandListByManagerCall
                                        .workereventDesc(
                                      listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse
                                          .jsonBody,
                                    ).toString(),
                                    fname: GetCandListByManagerCall.workerfname(
                                      listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse
                                          .jsonBody,
                                    ).toString(),
                                    lname: GetCandListByManagerCall.workerlname(
                                      listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse
                                          .jsonBody,
                                    ).toString(),
                                    dateEvent:
                                        GetCandListByManagerCall.dateEvent(
                                      listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse
                                          .jsonBody,
                                    ).toString(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
```

I might be wrong with that as well but let me know.
The response I get while running the app:
[image]

```
dynamic getJsonField(dynamic response, String jsonPath) {
 final field = JsonPath(JsonPath).read(response);
 return field.isNotEmpty
  ? field.length > 1
     ? field.map((f) => f.value).toList() : field.first.value : null;
}
```

```
class GetCandListByManagerCall {
  static Future<ApiCallResponse> call({int? entityId}) {
     final body = {
             "token": "", //deleted in the post specifically
             "entityId": ${entityId},
             "pageNumber": 1,
             "rowsPerPage": 10,
             "search": ""
     };

     return Apimanager.instance.makeApicall(callName:'GetCandListByManager',....);
   } //the other parts in this line arent really helpful and have private info  

   static dynamic workerfname(dynamic response) => getJsonField(response, r'''$.fname''',);
   static dynamic workerlname(dynamic response) => getJsonField(response, r'''$.lname''',);
}
```

if there is any missing information to understand the problem more deeply tell me and i'll provide it.

Comment: could you please include getJsonField?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: @eamirho3ein updated the post with it

Comment: where other place you are using candList ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein if you are referencing the cantList[] itself then there is no other place except that line of code. if you mean GetCandListByManager then there are a few usages

Comment: do you have any class model to pars the json you get from api? if yes please include it too.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `JsonPath`. But my guess is that you need to leave out the `[]`. I think most flutter developers don't even use it. flutter's built-in json decoding works great. Don't really need `JsonPath`

Comment: @eamirho3ein i've updated it as you requested (tell me if thats what you intended), i've also noticed the comment of Ivo and i've tried it, which made the result a bit better but still not ideal as you can see

Comment: could you please also include the part that have api call?

Comment: Yes i've added the relevant parts of it @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create class model like this:

```
class CandModel {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  const CandModel({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
  });

  static CandModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    
    return CandModel(
      firstName: json['fname'],
      lastName: json['lname'],
    );
  }
}
```

then pars your api like this, instead of this:

```
final num = getJsonField(listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody, r'''$.candList''',).toList();
```

use this:

```
final data = listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody['candList'] as List;
   List<CandModel> cands = data.map((e) => CandModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

then use it in you list view like this:

```
SworkerContainerWidget(
    desc: GetCandListByManagerCall.workereventDesc(
         listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody).toString(),
    fname: cands[index].firstName,
    lname: cands[index].lastName,,
    dateEvent:GetCandListByManagerCall.dateEvent(
          listViewGetCandListByManagerResponse.jsonBody).toString(),
)
```